# Self-Dual MDS Codes

Tags: coding-theory

*My question:* Is it possible to introduce some class of [Self-Dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_code) [MDS Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound) over finite field $GF(2^q)$

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just asking whether these codes exist? (they do)

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yahh I know that this code exist like this [artice](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4595330/) but I want to see that are there other methods for construction of this class of codes, just this.

Comment: If you type "self-dual MDS" into google scholar you will find lots of articles.